# Interrupt Priority in ARM

Tags: arm, interrupt

In ARM , **Interrupt Priority** is used. How is priority decided.
Is it done at hardware level or software level.

**Hardware level** - Is there an option in Interrupt Controller to set the interrupt priority.

**Software level** - Priority is calculated by the kernel and the corresponding interrupt handler is executed based on priority.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to add the [tag:homework] tag.

Answer (score 1):

The priority of interrupts is determined by the interrupt controller. And the interrupt controller should be programmable for this configuration.

For hardware interrupt, there is no software level priority, so far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Arm refers to interrupts as a subset of exceptions.

The first three exceptions have the highest priority, and their priority may not be changed. These are Reset, NMI, and Hard Fault.

Exception 4 to 15 priority can be set with the SCB, System Control Block.

Other exception priorities are set with the NVIC registers.

To learn more, read the Arm architecture manual. Chip manuals tend to gloss over the core details.